# Create border matric with indices on all four sides

Tags: bordermatrix

I have tried to use the command \bordermatrix but struggle to get it to work when all for sides has an index. The matrix I'm trying to replicate look like this

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: You have not accepted  a single answer to your questions -- This will hold off users to help you most likely

Comment: Hi, I have left my previuos posts because they answers I got had helped. I can't erase any questions outdated. I am suppose to answer my own questions??

Comment: hi again, I know this is off-topic. But geeh what I have searched for the delete button. I've benn on my profile, gone into questions and looking for a delete button. But this is nowhere to be found. Please help

Comment: You can't delete questions which have an answer!!! That's on purpose. There's a checkmark at the left side of the answer. Click on it to accept it and thereby appreciating the work of others or leave it, thereby disrespecting the works others have done for you. Here: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Well. No wonder I can't find it because I don't have the check mark only a star instead. No way I can close any of my questions.

Comment: Orongo, the check mark is at the answers of course, not at the question of ;-)